# this formula uses scope which is not presently supported for evaluation - is this relate to my O365 license type?

Tags: warnings, powerapps

I want to group my Gallery then I follow training on Youtube, here was my formula  :: GroupBy(MCUT,"Machine_Eng","GBY") then i move to item on Gallery and put formula on Title.Text = ThisItem.GBY then I found this messgae

"this formula uses scope which is not presently supported for evaluation" and also have small X in red circle.

Here is my screen ---

[image]

Here are my question

1. is this about limitation for my O365 license?
2. how to check my license type?

thank you in advance for all helps ^__^

Answer (score 1):

This error is shown only in the "watch expression", meaning that it won't be able to show you its value under the formula bar. That is because in a gallery there will be many rows, and the value of 'ThisItem' will vary among each row and thus the editor can't know which value to choose. This is true regardless of which license you have.

The error that you have is something different. If you hover the mouse on the term 'GBY' over the squiggly red line, you will see more information about the error. Based on the image, it looks like you are trying to use this expression in a label - and since GBY is a table (the group of MCUT rows that have a common 'Machine_Eng' value), this cannot be used in a label.

Comment: Hi Carlos, you're correct, I use Gallery's default title to express my result.  Then should I use dropdown to display my result?  Thanks for your help Carlosfigueira

Comment: It depends on what you want to display... If you want to display all of the rows, then you have many choices, such as using a label (but using a function such as Concat to concatenate the rows into a single text value), a drop down, another gallery, among others.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turns out that the column I was using allowed multiple entries.  When I changed the column, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, you made me realize I had changed the List column as "multiple selection", allowing it to be an array. Reverting to single selection did the trick to get the app back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else has this error and it is for a record type slap .value at the end and see if it clears.